# Automatically reconnect to ssh after suspend

Tags: bash, ssh, proxy

I'm using ssh as a SOCKS5 proxy, connecting to my personal server. When my system is suspended or I lose internet connection, the ssh will eventually time out, forcing me to manually reconnect. How can I configure my system to automatically reconnect as soon as an internet connection is established?

Comment: Did you happen to try any solutions yet that didn't happen to work?

Comment: I wrote a bash script for the ssh however right now I am manually executing it. I'm unsure about how I would get this script to run automatically when an internet connection is established.

Comment: you mean  `while ping -c 1 remotehost; do ssh remoteuser@remotehost; done`   does not work?

Comment: Check out `autossh` ...

Comment: I created a SystemD service to reconnect the ssh https://github.com/yurt-page/sshtunnel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to have a "reverse ssh" script like

```
laddr=*:0
host=some_user@some.host.com
port=some_port

while :; do
    t0=$(date +%s)

    ssh -R "$laddr:localhost:22" \
       -o BatchMode=yes \
       -o CheckHostIP=no \
       -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes \
       -o ServerAliveInterval=15 \
       -o ConnectTimeout=15 \
       -p "$port" "$host"

    t1=$(date +%s)
    sleep "$((60 / (t1 - t0 + 1)))"
done
```

which was supposed to try to connect immediately after the connection was lost, but wait a minute if ssh was terminating immediately, in order not to hammer the server or run a wild loop.

But I have long time ago replaced it with something better -- "service"-like.

Systemd & co are probably offering similar features.

Comment: Nice idea but the `sleep "$((60 / (t1 - t0 + 1)))"` doesn't really work. Just make a check that uptime is less that 60 https://github.com/yurt-page/sshtunnel/blob/master/sshtunnel.sh#L135