# How can I find IP address of my MacOS Laptop that others can ssh connect to?

Tags: ssh, ip, macos, internet, ip-address

My MacOS laptop does not have a static Public IP. I just connect to the Internet on my MacOS Laptop using a wifi connection.

There is a server having static non-changing IP in another country that needs to connect to my Laptop using `ssh` and perform some tasks.

How can I get my MacOS Laptop IP from the command line that I can give to the server Team to connect to my Laptop.

I tried to give them the public IP of my MacOS i.e "103.248.203.94", using google's "what is my IP" search, and also using

```
host myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com
Using domain server:
Name: resolver1.opendns.com
Address: 208.67.222.222#53
Aliases: 

myip.opendns.com has address 103.248.203.94
```

I'm also able to connect to localhost 22 on my MacOS like below affirming the service is running:

```
$telnet localhost 22
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
```

But, the Server Team is not able to connect to my Public IP even though the ssh is setup alright.

Can you please suggest ?

Comment: There's no way to do that if you're behind a NAT. You can however open a *reverse ssh* channel to that server with `ssh -N -R 3322:localhost:22 user@remote_server` and then the people from `remote_server` could connect to your laptop with `ssh -p 3322 your_user@localhost` (assuming that you have a working ssh server listening on port 22 on your laptop)

Comment: This works @user414777 but prompts for password despite ssh keys setup between the systems.  How can I make it passwordless using ssh-keys ? I guess the ssh key setup will be different for this approach. Please suggest?

Comment: of course you have to `ssh-copy-id` or similar in both directions

Comment: I did and ssh from localhost to remote_server works but when the remote guys try to execute commands on my laptop using  `ssh -p 3322 your_user@localhost 'uptime'` they get prompted for my laptop's password.

Comment: This is how i setup my ssh. 1. On my Laptop generated ssh public and private keys for `Laptop_user` and copied the public key to authorized_keys on self (Laptop) as well as on remote_server. 2. On the remote_server generated ssh public and private keys for `remoteserver_user` and copied public key to authorized_keys on self (remote_server) as well as on the Laptop. 3. Ran `ssh -N -R 3322:localhost:22 remoteserver_user@remote_server` on Laptop 4. Ran `ssh -p 3322 Lptop_user@localhost` on remote server where it is prompting for password. Please suggest.

Comment: `ssh-copy-id -p 3322 Lptop_user@localhost` from the remote server. But of course, there a 100 things that may go wrong ;-)

Comment: Please put answers in answers.

Comment: Your @user414777 solution worked passwordless;  however there is one issue. When I fire the below on command on `remoteserver`  after an interval of 2 or 3 hoursI get the below error `$  ssh -p 3322 Laptop_user@localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 3322: Connection refused`. Any solution to that please ?

Comment: @Ashar it looks like your tunnel has been broken -- either because the route has changed or something else. You should make a script which keeps it up, you can use [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/571768/414777) as an inspiration. However, keep in mind that reverse ssh is a quick and dirty hack, not a 100% vpn and wifi roaming solution ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reverse tunnel. In the following example, you will forward local port 22 from your MacOS laptop, to port 2222 on remote server. Assuming that remote server has a static IP address of X.X.X.X, you can create a reverse tunnel using following command from your laptop:

```
ssh -fnN -R 2222:localhost:22 server-user@X.X.X.X
```

On the other end (server side), the users will SSH to the linux server as per normal,and then they will start a new SSH session to your laptop using following command (from within the Linux server)

```
ssh -p 2222 laptop-user@localhost
```

Comment: can accommodate the below issue in your answer please?     Problem: When I fire the below on command on remoteserver after an interval of 2 or 3 hours then i get the below error `$ ssh -p 3322 Laptop_user@localhost ssh: connect to host localhost port 3322: Connection refused.` Any solution to that please ?

Comment: You may consider using the following tools:  screen https://www.networkworld.com/article/3441777/how-the-linux-screen-tool-can-save-your-tasks-and-your-sanity-if-ssh-is-interrupted.html

or mosh https://mosh.org/

Comment: Please update your answer with `remoteuser` instead of `user` `ssh -fnN -R 2222:localhost:22 remoteuser@X.X.X.X` ... both the `ssh` commands should have different users.

Comment: Edited the answer as per request

Comment: I got a different further to this question here if you can have a look: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/633857/how-to-check-for-active-reverse-ssh-tunnel-connections-on-macos

Comment: Will respond shortly

Answer (score 1):

Your internet router probably has a NAT, because we have run out of IP addresses (The last set of IP addresses was issued a few years back).

The address that you get from "what is my IP" will be the IP address of your router.

## What to do.

You need to set up port forwarding: so that when someone tries to connect to part 22 of your router, the request is forwarded to your device.

Do something like the following (it will vary in every router, some are easier than others).

- Go in to the config of your router.
- Find the DHCP setup (it probably is not call this).
- Give your device a static IP address.
- Find the bit for port forwarding.
- Set up a port forwarding rule.