# How to check for active ssh port forwarding connections on MacOS

Tags: ssh, process, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding, macos

On my local MACOS I setup a reverse ssh tunnel using the below command.

```
ssh -fnN -R 2222:localhost:22 remoteuser@remotelinuxhost
```

And then my MACOS is controlled by the remote linux host which fires commands using the below

```
ssh -p 2222 macosuser@localhost 'rm -i /tmp/ooo*.'
remove /tmp/ooootest.log?
```

Similarly

```
ssh -p 2222 macosuser@localhost 'sleep 300'
```

My requirement is to check on my MacOS; if there is any active command fired from linux host which is currently executing / active.

On my MacOS; I tried commands like `who` and `w` but they don't reflect the active connection running commands which are fired remotely from the Linux host.

Thus, can you please suggest how can I see the established connection for `rm` or `sleep` commands on my MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an opensource cross platform tool called sysdig. This tool will show you all the commands that where executed by users, directories that were visited by users. How to install and use sysdig instructions found [here](https://www.tecmint.com/sysdig-system-monitoring-and-troubleshooting-tool-for-linux/)