# How to rebuild a broken SSH session automatically from the remote site?

Tags: ssh, scripting, remote, tunneling

I use Reverse SSH Tunnel behind a Customer-Grade NATed GSM Modem. This sounds terrible but it is fine. I use the following instruction:

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -f -N -T -R12345:localhost:22 domain.com -i private_key.ppk
```

The session works fine. I can use the tunnel and I am able to connect my computer despite it is not available from the public internet because the CG-NAT.
Until now it is okay. But I need a solution for that case when the connection goes down. How could I catch it on the remote site ? And if I can catch it what do I need to do ? Would be fine configuring a cron job or something like this but at this point I need the help of the community. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The remote site will catch and die automatically when the tunnel goes down. You have to restart the tunnel from the *local* side when ssh exits, and for that the `-f` of ssh stays in the way. This [stupid script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/571768/369832) used to do it for me. An improvement would be to pass the `-y` option the ssh, so it print error messages to syslog instead of stderr.

Comment: BTW, I don't think you need the `-T` option with `-N`

Comment: First of all: your nickname is rock. :D Thank you for the script. Tomorrow I try to adapt it. And thank you for the hint about -y I try it as well. Good night.

Comment: @CocaineMitch `-T` has been removed and `-y` has been added to my command above. Let's talk about the script. `laddr=*:0` \ `host=domain.com` \ `port=12345` \ `ssh -R "$laddr:localhost:22" ` \  `-p "$port" "$host"` I do not understand the **laddr** variable. Could u pls explain that part a bit ? Thx.

Comment: `laddr` is the address:port ssh should bind on and listen on the remote machine; change it as you see fit -- e.g. set it to `laddr=12345` as in your example (if no address is given, it will only listen on the loopback interface)

Comment: Fine. I modified the script according to your instruction. What I supposed to do now ? Simple start it and let run ? And it will handle automatically the disconnected session ? Should I create a cron task and put this script into it when machine is restarting ? Thx.

Comment: Yes, I just had that called (in the background, as with `sh /path/to/that/script &`) from `/etc/rc.local`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the inspiration for @Cocaine Mitch
I wrote my first shell script ever.
It checks the running processes and if the ssh is missing from the list another script is executing.
The script is scheduled by cron that makes this check in every 20 minutes. (Cron job definition: `*/20 * * * * * root /root/checkscript.sh`)

```sh
#!/bin/sh
logger "######### ssh_check.sh script is startig."
i=0
logger "Value of initial i = " $i
txt1=$(ps ax | grep "[s]sh -p 22 -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -y -f -N -R12345:localhost:22 mydomain.com")
if [ ! -z "$txt1" ]
then
    i=$((i+=1))
fi

logger "Value of txt1 = " $txt1
logger "Value of i = " $i

txt2=$(ps ax | grep "[s]sh -p 22 -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -y -f -N -R12346:localhost:80 mydomain.com")
if [ ! -z "$txt2" ]
then
    i=$((i+=1))
fi

logger "Value of the txt2 = " $txt2
logger "Value of i = " $i
    
if [ $i == 0 ]
then
    /root/ssh_tunnel.sh
    logger "Given patterns were not found. SSH Tunnel script is starting."
    logger "####### ssh_check.sh script log is closing."
else
    logger "At least one pattern has been found. Tunnel must be opened."
    logger "###### ssh_check.sh script log is closing."
fi
```

Content of ssh_tunnel.sh script

```sh
#!bin/sh
ssh -p 22 -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -y -f -N -R12346:localhost:80 mydomain.com
ssh -p 22 -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -y -f -N -R12345:localhost:22 mydomain.com
```