# How do I get an ssh command to run on boot?

Tags: ssh, boot

I've tried putting an ssh comand in `/etc/rc.local` but it doesn't work.

/etc/rc.local:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -fN -R 8080:localhost:80 -i /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu@50.0.0.1 >> /tmp/ssh-nginx.out 2>>/tmp/ssh-nginx.err
```

/tmp/ssh-nginx.err:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /tmp/ssh-nginx.err 
ssh: connect to host 50.0.0.1 port 22: Network is unreachable
```

Adding the same command in crontab (line is `@reboot /etc/init.d/ssh-nginx`) gives the same output.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: You should retry the command until `50.0.0.1` is reachable, and for that, the `-f` option stays in the way. See my comments [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/668711/how-to-rebuild-a-broken-ssh-session-automatically-from-the-remote-site#comment1260075_668711). My [script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/571768/369832) may not the best, but that's the general idea -- you should retry the connection until it's up and after it went down.

Comment: if i'm no wrong the `/etc/rc.local` is deprecated.

Comment: Might try with a cronjob (`@reboot`)

Comment: I've tried with cron. It still runs the command before the network is available.

Comment: your answer is by far the best.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution that works. Feedback would be appreciated.

Create an ssh script like this in `/usr/local/bin/autossh-tunnel`

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -N -R 11001:localhost:80 -o ServerAliveInterval=30 -i /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu@50.0.0.1
# not necessary, but you may want to use autossh instead: /usr/bin/autossh -M 0 -q -N -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -R 11001:localhost:80 -i /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu@50.0.0.1
```

And a service file in `/etc/systemd/system/autossh-tunnel.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=AutoSSH tunnel
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/autossh-tunnel
# Remove restarts if the command is just a one-off
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And run `sudo systemctl enable autossh-tunnel.service` to get it to start on boot. (start it now with `sudo systemctl start autossh-tunnel.service`)

Also, consider using a VPN instead of SSH tunnels.